# How do I defeat Early Poptropica on Poptropica.com?

Tags: poptropica

In the game [PopTropica](http://www.poptropica.com) I'm having trouble in defeat the Early Poptropica. What's the best strategy to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

Explore the island, pick up things, give things away until you win.